# How to convert coroutines Flow<List<T>> to List<T>

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How to convert kotlinx.coroutines.flow list to normal data class list.

Comment: You can't directly convert it to list but all you can do is consume it as list using methods like `collect` or `map`

Comment: If you mean a Flow that emits a List<T> once, and you just want that list: `someFlow.first()`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since you want to go from a flow of nested lists to a single list, you need a flat-mapping operation:

```
suspend fun <T> Flow<List<T>>.flattenToList() = 
        flatMapConcat { it.asFlow() }.toList()
```

Example of usage:

```
suspend fun main() {
    val flowOfLists: Flow<List<Int>> = flowOf(listOf(1, 2), listOf(3, 4))
    val flatList: List<Int> = flowOfLists.flattenToList()
    println(flatList)
}
```

Comment: If there was, I guess this answer wouldn't need to be written :)

Answer (score 0):

As @JeelVankhede mentioned in the comment, you can use `collect` to consume the flow.

For example:

```
   fun tickets(): Flow<List<Ticket>> {
        return flow {
            // first share whats in db before re-fetching
            ticketDao.selectAllTickets().collect { emit(it) }
            updateTickets()
            emitAll(ticketDao.selectAllTickets())
        }
    }
```